# UICollectionView horizontal cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a view collection with more than one cell.

The first cell must contain a time line.

As you see in the image can not print the time line across horizontally.

***How can I print this cell horizontally?***

**my code:**

```
      class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
var year = 2000
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


      func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 200
     }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 97, height: 33)

}


     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyViewCell

        cell.textView.text = "\(year)";
        year++;

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: all cells horizontally?

Comment: not really. A total of three cells, only two horizontal and one vertical only. In this link: you can see what I do: http://code4app.net/ios/Static-column-table/50fe649d6803fa7b65000001

Comment: decrease cell size so that Two cell will come in horizontal width.and assign three cells in section .

Comment: noOfYears/3 should be your sections.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding. Why dimuire cell size? I simply want the cells to be printed one after the other in a horizontal

Comment: you want collection view like your link? m working onn that

Comment: it is better to use scroll view if you want to scroll horizontal

Comment: I have edited with a new code, but don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default collection view layout should already work like this (from Apple Docs):

[image: collection view layout]

It's how you set the year for each cell. Don't use `year++` for that. Make it respond to the `indexPath.row`:

```
cell.textView.text = "\(2000 + indexPath.row)";
```

There is also a great tutorial available here: [UICollectionView Swift Tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-collection-view-using-swift/)

Comment: ok but I want the cell does not wrap line. I want to create a time line and move with the horizontal scroll

Comment: ok, then you need to change the scroll direction of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout and change the height of the cells / collection view to only allow 1 row

Comment: How i change the height of the cells ? I have tried changing the storyboard and then clicking CollectionView cellsize and I diminuuto height. But it does not work

Comment: You should implement the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and provide the correct size in collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: (see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html)

Comment: But there is no need to implement the method: sizeForItemAtIndexPath. The size of the item can also change from the storyboard. But I do not understand why changing the size should be printed in a single line

Comment: I've tried it, is to change the storyboard that as I advised her. But it does not work